# Extracting H2o Cross Validation Results

Tags: r, cross-validation, h2o

I am using H2o library in R and have a slight confusion that you learned people might be able to help with. I am not sure how to interpret the output from `h2o.cross_validation_predictions()` as it appears to have all rows and not just those used as the test measurement?

I have a dataset of 240 rows & 5 o/p classes.  I have a model called deep with parameters:

```
nfold=FOLDS
keep_cross_validation_predictions=TRUE,
keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment=TRUE
```

I run the algorithm and the `summary(deep)` gives me: e.g.

```
Cross-Validation Metrics Summary: 
                              mean          sd cv_1_valid cv_2_valid
accuracy                0.40934372 0.021433437 0.43965518 0.37903225
err                      0.5906563 0.021433437  0.5603448 0.62096775
err_count                     71.0   4.2426405       65.0       77.0
logloss                  1.9856012 0.049440455  2.0555205  1.9156818
max_per_class_error            1.0         0.0        1.0        1.0
```

I can see the results for fold 1 and fold 2.

I want to analyse the predictions for each fold myself.  I use:

```
h2o.cross_validation_predictions(deep)
```

This gives a list of two elements, one for each fold BUT why are there 240 rows? Each fold should split to 120 train and 120 test, so I had anticipated these results to be for the 120 records of the test?

```
[[1]]
  predict        p1         p2         p3         p4           p5
1       1 0.8608196 0.01197437 0.02884958 0.07538831 0.0229681450
2       1 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000000
3       1 0.7204473 0.08612677 0.08648538 0.09837615 0.0085644254
4       1 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000000
5       2 0.3437493 0.48853368 0.14723671 0.01996180 0.0005185645
6       2 0.2155752 0.63492769 0.13477110 0.01435626 0.0003697219

[240 rows x 6 columns] 

[[2]]
  predict          p1        p2         p3         p4           p5
1       1 0.000000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000000
2       2 0.013206830 0.9334008 0.02128286 0.03146788 0.0006416512
3       1 0.000000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000000
4       2 0.006375454 0.9370140 0.03062428 0.02546406 0.0005222259
5       1 0.000000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000000
6       1 0.000000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000000

[240 rows x 6 columns]
```

I can use `h2o.cross_validation_fold_assignment(deep)`, which gives me:

```
  fold_assignment
1               0
2               1
3               0
4               1
5               0
6               0
```

I assume 0 is fold 1 and 1 is fold 2 and this indicates the row in the dataset used for that fold (a little inconsistent use of starting at 0 or at 1).

Do I filter the results from `h2o.cross_validation_predictions(deep)`, e.g. for [[1]] I select all the records indicated as “0” in the fold assignment?

Will this then give me just the records used to calculate the metrics for that fold?

I have tried the documentation and numerous searches – it is almost certainly my lack of ability – but help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/cross-validation.html?using-cross-validated-predictions#using-cross-validated-predictions) is the part of the documentation that should answer your question.

For your convenience these are the key pieces of that section of the user guide:

*Each cv-model produces a prediction frame pertaining to its fold. It can be saved and probed from the various clients if `keep_cross_validation_predictions` parameter is set in the model constructor.
These holdout predictions have some **interesting properties**.[...]*

*and they contain, unsurprisingly, predictions for the data held out in the fold. **They also have the same number of rows as the entire input training frame with 0s filled in for all rows that are not in the hold out.***